# What is wrong with my program in C?

Tags: c, linux, file

[Code link](https://ideone.com/p8QLiB)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define OS_TYPE    "/proc/sys/kernel/ostype"
#define OS_RELEASE "/proc/sys/kernel/osrelease"
#define V_BUFF     30

static const char * get_value(const char * file_path)
{
        static char value[V_BUFF];
        FILE *fd;

        memset(value, 0, sizeof(value));

        if ((fd = fopen(file_path, "r")) == NULL) {
                fputs("Fopen function error.\n", stderr);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        while (fgets(value, V_BUFF, fd) == NULL) {
                fputs( "Fscanf function error.\n", stderr);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        fclose(fd);

        return value;
}

int main(void) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s%s", get_value(OS_TYPE), get_value(OS_RELEASE));

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Where's wrong?
Why the result r same?

If added a `fflush` in `while` or out of `while`, the result also same.

Plz help me, tell what reason.
Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code; not its link. :)

Comment: Divide it into two `fprintf`s.

Comment: `while (fgets(value, V_BUFF, fd) == NULL)` looks suspect

Comment: @BLUEPIXY For some reason, i need this in a one.

Comment: @GOLDEN_gun It is not possible to use the same memory simultaneously for different purposes.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks, i know that now.

Comment: Please state what is wrong with the program. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 2):

The arguments are evaluated *then* passed to `fprintf` to format them.

Since there's only one memory area (`static`) for both results, the last function call "wins" and you get twice the same result (note that order of evaluation is implementation defined, so you could get twice the first result, or twice the second)

Quickfix: as BLUEPIXY suggested, you could call `fprintf` twice:

```
    fprintf(stdout, "%s", get_value(OS_TYPE));
    fprintf(stdout, "%s", get_value(OS_RELEASE));
```

To fix that properly you'd have to allocate memory using `malloc` (`char *value = malloc(V_BUFF);`), but in that case you'd have to store the pointer to be able to free it, or pass an extra argument to the function, as a buffer to use internally, like some standard functions do.

```
const char * get_value(const char * file_path, char *value)
{
    ...
    return value;
}
```

now you can get your call in one line with separate buffers and no memory leaks:

```
char vbuf[V_BUFF],obuf[V_BUFF];
fprintf(stdout, "%s%s", get_value(OS_TYPE,vbuf), get_value(OS_RELEASE,obuf));
```

Comment: I'm ok with the nitpicking. This question is basic enough, let's not write false stuff.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Comment: consider accepting the answer if it solves your problem: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358868/how-can-i-accept-an-answer